# Not getting the Outlook.MAPIFolder reference in VBA project

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using outlook 2016. The VBA editor gives intellisense for stuff in the Outlook namespace. However, MAPIFolder is not available.

[image]

My first thought, was that it could be a reference problem. Hence checked Tools > References. I only see some IMAPI references.

[image]

However, adding them did not solve the issue. Further, I thought there must be some dll that does the trick. Hence, googled, and got mapi32.dll. It usually resides in the System32 folder. However, VBA doesn't allow to add that either...

What is the correct reference I must add? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Per MSDN - MAPIFolder interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder(v=office.12).aspx)*** is deprecated Instead use the interface **[Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder(v=office.12).aspx)** to access all method, property, and event members of the COM object **[Folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder.aspx)**, I believe Office 2003 and below Versions use **[MAPIFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolderevents_12_event.aspx)**

***[MAPIFolder Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa210948(v=office.11).aspx)***